# multiple in clause gocql not executing

Tags: go, cql

Problem with running a query from gocql but it runs okay from the console.

```
  DELETE            
    FROM 
        honda.car_v1 
    WHERE 
        (id in ?)
        AND
        (user_id in ?)
```

I tried running this in cql console, it runs perfectly but when i run it via https://github.com/gocql/gocql it does not give any error, yet the rows are still there. I wonder what did i do wrong.

Comment: need code to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

id := []int{10,20,30}

userData := []int{1,2,3,4}

It has nothing to do with the gocql itself. turns out the way I convert the arrays into comma separated values turned the list into string which is invalid because

id is now "10,20,30" and userData is now "1,2,3,4" and it's sent to the query like this

```
DELETE            
FROM 
    honda.car_v1 
WHERE 
    (id in '10,20,30')
    AND
    (user_id in '1,2,3,4')
```

where i needed them to be like

```
DELETE            
FROM 
    honda.car_v1 
WHERE 
    (id in 10,20,30)
    AND
    (user_id in 1,2,3,4)
```

so i just do a simple string formatting to solve the problem.